# Client Authentication with API passes null values for username and password C#

Tags: c#, api, authentication

I am trying to authenticate a user using API, for some reason, this code (inside the using statement) passes a null username and password to the controller.
I placed stop points on the controller and the just before the using statement, the username and password are coming in correctly up until the using statement. once we pass it, in the controller, the incoming parameters are null.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5063/api/authentication/authenticate",
            (new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")))
```

The Entire code from the client side:

```
        public async Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string username, string password) // task essentially returning void for async method, it returns a task, saying we are waiting to finish
    {          
        var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("username", username ),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("password", password )
            });

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5063/api/authentication/authenticate",
            (new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthenticatedUser>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my controller:

```
[Route("api/authentication")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public static Users user = new Users();

    public AuthenticationController(IConfiguration configuration, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        _userRepository = userRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepository));
    }

    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public ActionResult<string> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticationRequestBody request)
    {
        //Step1: validate the username/password
        var user = _userRepository.ValidateUserCredentials(
            request.UserName, request.Password);
        
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        // IdentityModel.Tokens
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["Authentication:SecretKey"]));
        
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
            securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var claimsInfo = new List<Claim>();
        claimsInfo.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId.ToString()));
        claimsInfo.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
        claimsInfo.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName));

        var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            _configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
            _configuration["Authentication:Audience"],
            claimsInfo,
            DateTime.UtcNow, // start time, cannot use token before this time
            DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4), // end time, cannot use after this time
            signingCredentials
            );
        // view token at jwt.io or https://www.jstoolset.com/
        var userToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
            .WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
        
        return Ok(new {AccessToken = userToken});
    }
}
public class AuthenticationRequestBody
{
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
}
```

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're doing FormUrlEncoded inside your auth method but you're passing in json. You'll have to pass in a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>instead of JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Comment: Thank you for the response, change the FormURLEncoded to a list and then passed it to the using statement, now I am getting the using like so (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5063/api/authentication/authenticate",(formData))). 
Now I am getting the error "unsupported media type" +  response {StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}} System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Comment: You need to change your Content-Type header to text/html or text/xml

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following changes and they solved my error:
first modified my authenticate method on the client side like so:

```
        public async Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string username, string password) // task essentially returning void for async method, it returns a task, saying we are waiting to finish
    {
        // we have to send FormUrlEncodedContent for the username/password  and the type
        // this will create the user data that we will send to the API Endpoint (authentication)
        
        var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("username", username ),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("password", password )
            });

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5063/api/authentication/authenticate",formData))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthenticatedUser>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

also, I have modified my controller action to receive [FromForm] instead of [FromBody]

```
public ActionResult<string> Authenticate([FromForm] AuthenticationRequestBody request)
```

now my client is able to receive token from the API after authentication.
thanks